# How do I replace keys from a list of dictionaries with values from another dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts and a dict.

```
list_of_dicts = [
{'AssetId':'1234',
 'CreatedById':'02i3s',
 'Billable__c': True},
{'AssetId':'4567',
 'CreatedById':'03j8t',
 'Billable__c':True}
]

dict1 = {
'AssetKey':'AssetId',
'SourceRowCreatedBy':'CreatedById',
'FlagBillable':'Billable__c'}
```

I essentially want to replace the keys from `list_of_dicts` with the keys from `dict` if the key from `list_of_dicts` matches with the value from `dict`. So my output should look like:

```
new_list_of_dicts = [
{'AssetKey':'1234',
 'SourceRowCreatedBy':'02i3s',
 'FlagBillable': True},
{'AssetKey':'4567',
 'SourceRowCreatedBy':'03j8t',
 'FlagBillable':True}
]
```

The above was solved due with the help of @DYZ. Thank you!

EDIT:
Now I'm running into a situation where I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [
{'0123uvw': {'AssetId':'1234',
 'CreatedById':'02i3s',
 'Billable__c': True},
{'456xyz': {'AssetId':'4567',
 'CreatedById':'03j8t',
 'Billable__c':True}
]
```

How would I loop through these to update them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am using python 3.9.7. Please let me know if there is anything further I need to provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note: do not use `dict` as a variable name. It is a dictionary constructor. So, let's assume your second dictionary is called `dict1`.

Start by reversing it: swap the keys and the values to form another dictionary.

```
dict2 = {v: k for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Now, for each item in your list, look up the keys in the new dictionary:

```
[{dict2[k]: v for k,v in d.items()} for d in list_of_dicts]
# [{'AssetKey': '1234', 'SourceRowCreatedBy': '02i3s', 'FlagBillable': True}, 
# {'AssetKey': '4567', 'SourceRowCreatedBy': '03j8t', 'FlagBillable': True}]
```

Comment: I just added an edit to my post. I'm not really quite sure how I would loop through with a dictionary full of dictionary entries. I will try and solve this on my own tonight, but just wanted to get the comment out there. Thanks!

Comment: I think I'm struggling trying to get it in a list comprehension. I'm very new to this and can't figure out how to loop through everything in the proper order when it is in a list comprehension, but I realize this is the "pythonic" way to do it.